# undesired extra space above `\proof`

Tags: spacing, amsthm

In Theorems 1 and 2, there is extra space between the equation and the proof.  In Theorem 3, there isn't.  What is causing this in the case of Theorem 2 and how can I get the `\proof` command not to insert the extra space (without resorting to negative vspace)?  I wish to learn about the mechanics (I'm *not* looking for a package that colors my equations: I'm aware of those).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm,xcolor}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}


\begin{document}



\begin{theorem}
    blabla
    {\color{red}
    \begin{equation} 
    x
    \end{equation}}%
    \proof
    hi  
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}
    blabla
    \begin{equation} \color{red}
    x
    \end{equation}
    \proof
    hi  
\end{theorem}


\begin{theorem}
    blabla
        \begin{equation} {\color{red}
        x}
        \end{equation}%
    \proof
    hi  
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you nest the proof in the theorem?

Comment: Have you aware that you applied the scope of red color in three different ways? That matter ...

Comment: @bernard Ha.  Are you saying that for any theorem/lemma/etc, the \proof should go outside the environment?  That doesn't solve the excess spacing issue.

Comment: @Fran Yes, that's the point of the question.

Comment: Inside a theorem environment, you could set `\belowdisplayskip ` to be the same as `belowdisplayshortskip`.

Comment: I was hoping to redefine `\proof`

Comment: You should *never* use `\proof` in a document. Ever.

Comment: @egreg please explain

Comment: You should use `\begin{proof}<text of the proof>\end{proof}`.

Comment: @egreg I understood you recommend that, but not why you recommend it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package `amsthm` provides a `proof` *environment*. For implementation reasons, the command `\proof` exists, but should ***not*** be used in a document, because it opens an internal `trivlist` environment which is not properly closed.

Besides, the proof doesn't belong to the statement, so the environment should go outside `theorem`.

In order to color (part of) an equation, use `\textcolor{<color>}{<math>}`.

So the correct way to input the thing is

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm,xcolor}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
blabla
\begin{equation}
\textcolor{red}{x}
\end{equation}
\end{theorem}

\begin{proof}
hi
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

which has no strange spacing, as you can clearly see.

[image]

If you don't want the “tombstone” (aka “end-of-proof symbol”), just add

```
\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{}
```

before `\begin{document}`.

This said, you're free to shoot on your own foot, but using unsupported commands or syntax is, well, unsupported.

Comment: Thanks @egreg.  It doesn't solve my particular problem, but I'll accept your answer and start a new question.